# How can I use a hyperledger fabric network in IBM Blockchain Platform?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to get a locally hosted Hyperledger Fabric network (the test-network from Fabric itself) connected via the vscode plugin "IBM Blockchain Platform". I have been able to extract the wallet (added under "wallet" in vscode) and connection.json (added under "gateway" in vscode), but I still need to add the network itself (under "environments").

I can click the plus icon to add an environment, but I need to provide "node JSON files" to connect to it. I don't know what this is, and I can't find information on which format this is.

For the wallet and the gateway I can export them from the plugin to see what the desired format is, but for environments this is not possible.

Can someone tell me what format these "node JSON files" need to be in?

Answer (score 1):

The node json format information can be accessed through the extension README, [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/wiki/Common-tasks-and-how-to-complete-them#json-node-files)